# need backend for cordova mobile app with user auth and offline support

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, hybrid-mobile-app, pouchdb

I'm writing a hybrid app using Ionic / Cordova and am looking for a backend solution - I've looked at the likes of Firebase and Parse and none of the solutions are exactly what I need.
The app will have on the order of hundreds of entries by a user that can be grouped into selections (think ingredients that can be put into recipes).
My ideal scenario for backend:
1 - be able to store hierarchical data with several relations (in the case of an ingredient, there should be tags, configurable types, etc which should be manageable so there would potentially be many 'foreign key' scenarios)
2 - be able to cache all data locally - if a user starts up offline, i want them to be able to use the app entirely and when online, a sync would happen so that multiple devices would always be in sync
3 - allow for user management - that is, i want to register an account (ideally with options for fb/google/amazon/etc social logins) and then have access to data based on that account

So far I've tried implementing Firebase - was great excpet it doesn't work at all offline and PouchDB/Cloudant - seems decent enough but the NoSQL approach with no per-user permissions is being kind of problematic - i don't see how i can structure the data logically in such a way as to not cause security issues for users. also i don't see if users can register for accounts and have the system make tables for them automatically that only they can access
I've been reading up on other solutions but so far nothing seems to accomplish the seemingly easy task of transparent offline caching.

Comment: Questions like "What is the best" and "Please recommend a" aren't really on-topic for Stack Overflow. (A lot of people ask them anyway, however.)

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You can use couchDB and PouchDB at client side. You can take benefit of replication and sync. Check this link: http://devgirl.org/2014/12/30/sync-data-using-pouchdb-in-your-ionic-framework-app/ What if you encrypt the PouchDB data with appropriate salt (just a thought).

Comment: PouchDB/CouchDB is what I'm doing right now and it seems to be OK, though I still need to figure out how to register users and assign them to different databases.